# Comparing unknown number of variable in bash

Tags: bash

I have 1 to 4 linux server names in a configuration file, I will have to take those names out of the configuration file and assign them values (Floating point Value derived from linux commands). Now the number of server taken out of the configuration file may vary depending on the server availability(For example if a server is down for some reason we will remove the server from configuration file or comment it out) so Fixed number of server is 4 but it may reduce based on its availability, how do I compare the values derived and find out the least/minimum out of this ? It will be great if someone could provide suggestions on this.

Comment: Do you have an example configuration file? Are you literally just trying to figure out the smaller of two floating point numbers?

Answer (score 0):

To compare two floating point numbers you can use `bc`. It will print (*not* return) `0` for false and `1` for true statements:

```
$ bc <<< '2.01 > 2.1'
0
$ bc <<< '2.1 > 2.01'
1
$ bc <<< '2.01 >= 2.1'
0
$ bc <<< '2.01 >= 2.01'
1
```